# How do you compare (ReactNative, NativeScript) to Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, react-native, nativescript

Since [ReactNative/NativeScript] uses JavaScriptCore/V8 **JIT** interpreters and not compiling it so, is it strong enough for building all types of apps e.g. (Mediaplayer, Photo Editing, etc…)?
And how do you compare it with Xamarin?
I heard Xamarin uses **AOT**; is it similar to (JavaScriptCore/V8) **JIT** interpreters?
And how often Xamarin uses **AOT** for all of the app or it compile the part of code to native and uses **AOT** for rest of it?

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it solves your question(acknowledging someone who is putting effort to answer your question) or add additional question on what is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin does AOT for its C# code, which will be run by open source port of .NET -Mono in non windows platforms like Android and iOS. [Here are some limitations on Xamarin AOT](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/)

In comparison, Nativescript with Angular 2+ can take advantage of the [Angular AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) for performance boot. More details [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/bundling-with-webpack#how-nativescript-dev-webpack-works).

[Here is a detailed comparison](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-and-xamarin) from Progress, the company that backs NativeScript and also provides UI elements for xamarin.

With more traction towards JS open source community, [JavaScript virtual machine growth](https://github.com/v8/v8) vs [Mono for .NET](https://github.com/mono/mono), current benchmarks, I would bet on NativeScript/React native more than Xamarin.

NativeScript / React Native is a good bet, including your media player kind of app.. [here is a sample](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-videoplayer) you can give it a try.

Hope it helps.